# Numerical solution of Bethe ansatz equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, computational-physics, software, integrable-systems

In this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.14202, the authors plot the solution of coupled non-linear algebraic equation (Bethe Ansatz Equations):

\begin{equation}
k_j L=2\pi I_j -\sum_{\beta=1}^M \theta\left(\frac{\sin(k_j) -\lambda_\beta}{u} \right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
-\sum_{j=1}^N \theta\left(\frac{\sin(k_j)-\lambda_\alpha}{u}\right)=2\pi J_\alpha +\sum_{\beta=1}^M \theta\left(\frac{\lambda_\alpha-\lambda_\beta}{2u}\right)
\end{equation}
Where $\theta(x)=2\arctan(x)$, $I_j$ is either integer or half integer depending on where $M$ is even or odd and $J_\alpha$ is also either integer or half-integer depending on whether $(N-M)$ is odd or even.

They were able to plot the for very high value of $N=L=2M=250$. A naive attempt to put the equations in Mathematica and try to solve it struggled for even for $N$ as small as $N=6$.

[image: Plot for L=N=2M=250]

For an example, even for much simpler Bethe equation like that of XXX model, using following Mathematica code, one can plot the roots $\Lambda_j$. But one can barely reach $L=6$ after that it takes a long time for it to find roots.

```
L = 4; M = L/2; prec = 20; workprec = 200;
solu = Flatten[(\[CapitalLambda][#1] &) /@ Range[M] /. 
NSolve[Table[((\[CapitalLambda][j] + I)/(\[CapitalLambda][j] - 
     I))^L == -Product[(\[CapitalLambda][j] - \[CapitalLambda][
       l] + 2 I)/(\[CapitalLambda][j] - \[CapitalLambda][l] - 
      2 I), {l, M}], {j, M}], Table[\[CapitalLambda][j], {j, M}], 
 WorkingPrecision -> workprec]];
 ComplexListPlot@solu
```

---

How do I possibly reproduce the result the result of the paper?

Note: The coupling constant in the paper are complex, thus the roots are not in real line but I would be happy to just have a plot for above written equations for real u and $N=L=2M=250$.

[image: Bethe roots for XXX model]

Comment: I don't know anything about Mathematica, so I'm assuming that `prec=20` means 20 decimal places of precision. If that is the case, have you considered that asking for 20 decimal places & working with 200 might be a bit on the extreme side? The needed memory and (probably?) custom Types needed for storing beyond IEEE precisions is probably larger than you expect. Try setting it to like 6 and 16.

Comment: Did you find a nice solution? I'm also curious about the answer. I found http://msstp.org/?q=node/4, which might help you.